How to log connection information on the host being used as ProxyJump?
I have a bastion host (BASTION) through which users connect to other servers (S1, S2, S3).
They connect using the following command
ssh -J username1@BASTION username2@S1

If someone connects this way, I want to log the username (username1), user's IP address, the target server (S1) IP address on the BASTION host.
How can I do this? I have tried configuring ForceCommand <path_to_script> on the BASTION's sshd_config to run a script with MATCH all, but that is running only if there is a direct login to the BASTION (ssh username1@BASTION), not when using the BASTION as the ProxyJump for another server.
I guess the issue here is that when connecting using the -J flag, the connection is forwarded to the target server without triggering a login shell?

TL;DR: Technically you can have some logging of that by running ssh server with DEBUG log level, but it's not recommended by the man sshd_config as it violates privacy. Tunneling requests are no less private thing than, say, shell commands.
Don't do it that way. Better collect this information from target servers. You can also record network activity of the bastion.
You can limit where bastion used can forward with PermitOpen, or disable forwarding altogether, even per-user.
Explanation: running ssh -J user1@bastion user2@target does ssh -o ProxyCommand="ssh -W target:22 user1@bastion" user2@target, so to the bastion host ProxyJump is just a TCP/IP forwarding channel request. The -W option is different from -L and -D in that it connects the channel to the stdin/stdout of the client process. This option also implies -T -N, so normally it causes the client to not request PTY and to not execute a remote command, but this can be overridden. All the difference between these options is made by the client, which never tells the server for what purpose it requests a forwarding — there is simply no place for that in the SSH protocol. The sshd process running on the server at best knows (and can possibly log) that some forwarding was requested, but only logs this information on the DEBUG level.
An SSH Connection protocol RFC 7254, sect. 7.2 TCP/IP Forwarding Channels states that forwardings aren't tied to sessions and may appear and disappear multiple times during a session:

Forwarded TCP/IP channels are independent of any sessions, and closing a session channel does not in any way imply that forwarded connections should be closed.

In OpenSSH client you can type ~C (only recognized immediately after return; the escape character can be changed), and the client command shell appears that lets you to request new forwardings or terminate existing ones without reconnecting. So these TCP/IP forwarding events are not connected to the SSH authentication events and at best could be logged separately.
Also such logging is not as useful as it may seem, because built-in TCP/IP forwarding is not the only way to forward the traffic through the SSH server. For example, I can use ssh -o ProxyCommand="ssh user1@bastion nc target 22" user2@target, I will still connect to the target through the bastion as before, but the outgoing connection (on the bastion) will be done by the netcat, not by the sshd, and sshd won't see it as a forwarding, and won't log it as a forwarded connection even in DEBUG mode or if you patch it (see below).
The only defininite way to log the network activity of your users is actually log the network activity of the server.
There is a question about logging forwardings (no answer accepted, so I can't mark as a duplicate). In turn, there is a link which suggests practical approach to the problem: patching the OpenSSH code. The patch is simple, but personally I consider this way out of the "reasonable management practices", and I am not sure it solves the problem completely and correctly. Totally not recommended.
